# Writing filesize and filepath of a folder to a text file with Python 3.7

Tags: python, text-files, filesize

I am using Python 3.7.
I want to check the file sizes of a directory with the file path to a text file.

This is my code:

```
import os
import glob


# folder path
folderpath = 'C:/Test'

# Get a list of files in my folder
list_of_files = filter( os.path.isfile,
                        glob.glob(folderpath + '*') )

# get list of files with the size in my folder
files_with_size = [ (file_path, os.stat(file_path).st_size)
                    for file_path in list_of_files ]

# Iterate over the files and write them to a file
for file_path, file_size in files_with_size:
    with open('c:/Test/filesize.txt', 'w') as f:
        print(file_size, ' -->', file_path)
```

I can print the result in the Python console, but I cannot manage to write my result to a text file.
Can anybody help me?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ameloriate your code following way

```
for file_path, file_size in files_with_size:
    with open('c:/Test/filesize.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(file_size, ' -->', file_path, file=f)
```

changes: use `a` (append) mode and use `f` as value for named argument `file` of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function.